# Log4j, how to put log file into dynamic directory location

Tags: java, logging, log4j

can anyone show me how can I put my log file with Log4j in my project location?
I want to put my log file into src/main/resources every time.
I don't want to care about me location on disk of my project, for sample: if I have my project in D:/project and after that I change my location project in C:/project I want to put my log file on every time on src/main/resources with out change this line to this

```
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\project
```

with this

```
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\project
```

Have anyone any idea? 
Thx in advance for help :)

Comment: Please see my answer and vote it correct if it works for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write logic to determine if your application is being run in `C:\...` or `D:\...` by retrieving the current directory and set a system variable say `"logPath"` as below

```
System.setProperty("logPath", myPath); // where myPath is either C:\... or D:\... based on your logic
```

Then use this property in `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${logPath}src\main\resources\MyApplicationLog.log
```

> Note : you would need to make sure that the system variable is set
>   before log4j is initialized.

Comment: can we use the same in log4j.xml also?

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable in your code using this code

```
System.setProperty("path", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

and change appender to be like that

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${path}/src/main/resources
```

Comment: I guess my answer explains the same fact ?